# Как изменить экземпляр объекта , который находится в другом классе

Tags: java, android, callback

В этом классе находится диалог , который запускается из другого класса, через экземпляр интерфейса, showDialog - метод интерфейса.

```
    public class One  extends AppCompatActivity implements ShowDialod{
      GameOverFragment gameOverFragment;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           gameOverFragment = new GameOverFragment();
      }

      public void showDialog() { 
         gameOverFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"GameOverFragment");       
       }

     }
```

Далее порождается дополнительный поток, в котором в определенный момент запускается этот диалог.

```
    class MainThread extends Thread implements Callback {

    One one;

    MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
        super();
        one = new One;
        one.gameOverFragment.registerCallBack(this); // но gameOverFragment = null;


    }

    @Override
    public void callingBack() {
       //код для обратного вызова
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // код выполняемый в доп.потоке
    }
}
```

Пробовал в классе One поставить геттер, 
 public GameOverFragment GetDialog(){
     return gameOverFragment;
}

но когда выполняю one.GetDialog, то получаю так же пустой,равный null gameOverFragment.

Вопрос почему?

Архитектура такова : Запускается класс One, далее создается доп.поток , в нем цикл и в один момент через метод интерфейса вызывается диалог. В конструкторе класса потока передаю экземпляр потока в диалог one.gameOverFragment.registerCallBack(this); чтобы в диалоге при закрытии сделать обратный вызов.

Comment: Сделал в классе One    gameOverFragment  статик. Теперь я могу к нему напрямую обратиться и всё работает. Но как же мне обойтись без статичного объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте перенести вызов `gameOverFragment = new GameOverFragment();` из `onCreate()` в конструктор класса `One`. Проблема здесь в том, что `onCreate()` срабатывает не сразу после создания объекта `Activity`, а только после того, как `Activity` отрисована.

Comment: Это понял. но вылез другой null.. Создам другой вопрос, думаю в этом продолжать будет не правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну уж 100500 раз говорилось не создавать `Activity` конструктором(`one = new One;`) - это новый пустой объект, в нём нет Вашего диалога, Вы его создавали совсем в другом объекте `One`, созданном СИСТЕМОЙ!!!
И именно этот объект Вы должны "добыть" в `MainThread` (передать в конструкторе, к примеру, или сеттером).
Но следует помнить, что лучше избегать ссылок на `Activity` в фоновых потоках или внимательно следить, чтобы она не "утекла"

Comment: кажется я в чем то еще ошибся.. я перенес из onCreate в конструктор gameOverFragment = new GameOverFragment(); Остальной код остался без изменений. Теперь в классе MainThread в конструкторе я получаю другой gameOverFragment. Не тот который gameOverFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"GameOverFragment");

Comment: Причина того что я получаю другой объект связана с тем, что вы пишете о том, что принять его в конструкторе(этого я сделать не могу) или получить через get (не знаю почему вы про сеттер, если мне нужно его получить)